# lwc - Can't re-render child component after array is updated

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the following properties in an lwc component:

```
editPropertiesMap = new Map();
editPropertiesView = [];
```

I have a function that edits values in `editPropertiesMap`, and at the end runs the following:

```
this.editPropertiesView = [...this.editPropertiesMap].map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
```

This is how its used in HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows pull-to-boundary="small">
        <template if:true={editPropertiesView}>
            <template for:each={editPropertiesView} for:item="prop">
                <template if:true={prop.value.availableForEdit}>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" key={prop.key}>
                        <c-edit-property obj={prop.value}></c-edit-property>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

The child components simply contains `@api obj` and it shows the values in some text box.

Every time i update `editPropertiesView`, i excpet the html to be re-rendered and that all of the child components will use the new values.

However, the values are not changed and i have no idea why.

Child component:

```
@api obj;

@track currentObj;

connectedCallback() {
    this.currentObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj));
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        <template if:true={currentObj}> 
            <lightning-layout-item size={currentObj.size} padding="around-small" class="paddingEditPanel">
                <lightning-input 
                    data-id={id} 
                    date-style="short" 
                    type={currentObj.type} 
                    value={currentObj.value} 
                    checked={currentObj.value} 
                    label={currentObj.label} 
                    onchange={handleInputChange} 
                    disabled={isDisabled}>
                </lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Based on some suggestions i googled:

- i tried to add `@track`
- i tried do a shallow copy like this:
  `this.editPropertiesView = [...this.editPropertiesView]`

nothing works, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the LWC has difficulties to see the change in the mapped value. Therefore I suggest to use a copy of individual values:

```javascript
this.editPropertiesView = [...this.editPropertiesMap].map(([key, value]) => {
    value = { ...value };
    return { key, value };
});
```

(This is only necessary, if values of the Map are changed and not just added and removed.)

Secondly, the `connectedCallback` of the child component is only executed once [when the component is inserted in the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-lifecycle-hooks-dom.html). In order to make the component reactive, I suggest a setter of the `obj` to set the `currentObj` (which then doesn't need a @track annotation):

```javascript
currentObj = {text: 'No data'};

@api
get obj() {
    return this.currentObj;
}
set obj(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.currentObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
    } else {
        this.currentObj = {text: 'No data'};
    }
}
```

In my example code I used a property "text", but you are likely to read something else. (Are you sure you need to `parse`/`stringify` at all?!)

Comment: Hi Felix, pls ignore the last line, i edited your answer instead of my question by accident.
I tried your solution but it didn't work. The child component is still not seeing the new values that were changed. i added the child cmp code, any more suggestions?

Comment: I've added information regarding the Javascript of the child component, which you added to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! using a setter worked